# Install multiple apps from Play Store with single click

Tags: google-play-store, installation

The requirement goes like this.

Requirement 1:

1. Install parent app from Play Store with 2 or 3 feature buttons.
2. Once clicked, it should download and install corresponding apps from Play Store. (Catch here: it *should not* go to Play Store and ask to install)

Or requirement 2:

1. Install parent app from Play Store with single clickable button.
2. Once clicked, it should cumulatively install 2 or 3 apps from Play Store.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're from Google, you can't, and for good reasons why Google prohibits it.

I assume you want to do this for better user-experience, in which they can conveniently install what they need with their consent. However, let's put aside that idea and think another possibility: *a seemingly-safe app can install rogue apps from Play Store automatically **without user's consent!***

There's a more detailed explanation on [an answer by ozbek on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23750375/2821954), in which you can only request Play Store to install an app silently *if your app is signed by Google*.